# Can I take the equal sign out?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a feedback form for my web page as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWglY.png)

However, if someone clicks on the 'submit' button, the email the page composes will contain the equal sign like this:

Your name:=abc
Your feedback:=efg

Here is my code:

```
 <form action=mailto:mail@domain.com method="post" enctype="text/plain" name="FeedbackForm">
                Your name: <br>
                <input type="text" size="24" name="Your name:"> <br>
                Feedback: <br>
                <textarea name="Your feedback:" rows="6" cols="50"> </textarea> <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Is there any way to strip out the equal sign?

Comment: that is ok for back end to have equal sign

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to live with the equal signs as long as you're using `form action=mailto:` because no processing is being done - the information is being converted directly to email. If your form was processed by a server-side script, using a different form action, such as `<form action="/submit-form.php">`then the script could format the email more beautifully. It could also save the results in a database or send an autoreply, so you should consider it. You can find examples and instructions online of [how to code an email form](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-contact-form-in-php--cms-32314), but you have to be careful about security. Companies will process forms for you, such as [EmailJs](https://www.emailjs.com/) or [JotForm](https://www.jotform.com/) if you don't have your own script.